# Abbreviations for GCP products

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Is there any general abbreviation for Cloud Functions, etc?
How about Cloud Functions for Firebase?

Sometimes, I use CF for “Cloud Functions” and Firebase Functions for “Cloud Functions for Firebase”

What do you think?

Comment: I wish they'd just pick short names instead of abbreviations. GCE? --> "Cloud VMs". GKE? --> "Cloud Kubernetes". Dataproc? --> This one is good.

Comment: Ah, your thinking seems to be correct. Google uses Gxx for most products and if the product name is moderately short, use fullname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Hirobat commented, Google seems to mainly use short name like Gxx. (ex: GCE, GKE, GCF)

Only if the short name is already exists(ex: Google Cloud Firestore -> GCF, same with Google Cloud Functions), or is moderately short(ex: BigQuery), use fullname.